# Is there a technique/tool to assist with rear derailleur high, low, and index alignment?

Tags: derailleur-rear

Everything I read gives this picture like this:

[image: pic from Park Tool]

Yet the reality of this alignment, it can be somewhat difficult.  Is there a better technique or tool to help get the high, low, and index shifting alignment perfect?  Or is visual vertical alignment the only way?

Comment: It's a combo of visual checks, testing, and gut feel.

Comment: At the LBS they mainly use their eyes to adjust LO/HI and their ears to adjust indexing. It takes practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otto makes a tool, combined with a smartphone app to assist with the alignment of the rear derailleur.

I have used it and it works fine on both 10 and 11 speed road setups.

[Website link](http://ottodesignworks.com/shop?field_product_type_value=otto).

Comment: Visual alignment is NOT the only way.  Thank you, very interesting.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained. Please describe the tool and how it is used. A picture would be excellent. That way, the answer is still helpful if the link dies or the product gets discontinued . Otherwise, your answer is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the first thing to [check is if the derailleur (usually the hanger) is bent](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-hanger-alignment). There is a tool for the case of a bent hanger, namely the Park Tool DAG-2. You should also visually inspect for the derailleur pulleys to be aligned in the right way.

Then, you do the [standard derailleur adjustments](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment), which you'll get right after practicing (limit screws, B-screw, indexing).

The whole thing becomes a combination of visual inspection and testing and practice, as DRH remarked in the comments. But most cyclists who are going to do their own maintenance will have to deal with this a bunch of times in their life time anyway, so they'll get used to it. And cyclists who don't do their own maintenance will likely just be fiddling with the indexing adjustment a bit and if something more is necessary (e.g. if they had a crash), they'd head to a shop.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a tool that does better than visual alignment.  Visual alignment will get you close.  Fine tuning needs to be done by testing the drivetrain, preferably on a stand or balanced upside-down first, then under pressure on the road or trainer.  Slight differences in tolerances (wear, frame geometry, etc.) mean even a perfect cog to cassette alignment might not work as smoothly or quietly in every case.  Also keep in mind the shifting and indexing at both extremes should be under control of the shifter, not the limiters.  The limiters just prevent catastrophe if something slips or otherwise screws up.  If you're shifter has to push against the limiter on the inside, you're putting undue stress on the system, increasing its likelihood of slipping, stretching, or shortening its life.

I've done the following dozens of times:

1. Make the cable is slack or disconnected.
2. Set the outer limiter (H-screw in your diagram) using your hands and eyes.  The spring pushes the derailleur out.  You'll want to be slightly too far out; you'll tighten it later.
3. Install the cable using instructions for your specific derailleur.  Usually, start adjusters to the most or close-to-the-most slack setting (adjuster rotated clockwise from the shifter's perspective).  Pull the cable taught by hand or using a cable puller.  Roll the adjuster until the derailleur is aligned with the smallest gear and spins quietly.  Assuming you have compatible shifters, everything else will be close.  Pedal and shift to the larger gears.  Loosen the inner limiter if necessary to get there.  (Remember to shift the front as well.  Crossing gears can result in a noisy drivetrain no matter how well the rear is aligned.)  Adjust alignment again if necessary.
4. Set the inner limiter close but not against the aligned position.  Again, the limiter should prevent the chain from coming off, but not interfere with the shifter's indexing.
5. Shift back to the smallest gear and do the same with that limiter if it's not already correct.
6. Test and keep adjusting as you ride and find the gear configurations you tend toward.

This is all pretty close to what Park Tools recommend: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment